# SignalR authentication from desktop client with identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net, authentication, signalr, identity, signalr-hub

This fall i wanted to learn and write client-server. The fall is over, app does not exist, so i'm asking for some help. I still can't understand how to make login with identity 2.0 from signalr hubs.

if want to connect to hub, do smth like

`hub.invoke("UsualLogin",login,password)` //server checks database and sends back code for login state and authenticates.

Also i wanna be able to do 
`hub.invoke("GoogleLogin")` //server asks google for auth, sends back smth to open browser if it's needed, but i don't want open browser for usual login. I don't want web page even exist.

I read tons of info, watched dozens of examples, but didn't understand how to do this. Can you make example, which only connects to hub, authenticates and starts [authorize] chat with himself? So i just could see how it's done and where it's done.

Ps: i'm not a lazy student, this is only for my personal project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first result from the google search `signalr authentication` is this:

> **Authentication and Authorization for SignalR Hubs - ASP.Net**
>   http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization

Which includes exactly the example you're asking for...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connection = new HubConnection("http://www.contoso.com/");
        Cookie returnedCookie;

        Console.Write("Enter user name: ");
        string username = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter password: ");
        string password = Console.ReadLine();

        var authResult = AuthenticateUser(username, password, out returnedCookie);

        if (authResult)
        {
            connection.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            connection.CookieContainer.Add(returnedCookie);
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome " + username);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Login failed");
        }    
    }

    private static bool AuthenticateUser(string user, string password, out Cookie authCookie)
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.contoso.com/RemoteLogin") as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        var authCredentials = "UserName=" + user + "&Password=" + password;
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authCredentials);
        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            authCookie = response.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        }

        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no it doesn't. in this example authenticates  on some site first, and then connects to hub with some auth cookies from site.

i want connect to hub, and when i send login command with login and password, hub should authenticate by himself (i'm trying now to use asp.net.controller from template to do it w/o any sites i don't need), and do smth with client connection (there is context.user, who needs to be upgrated into authenticated version, but it's readonly)

it's another problem for me right now: may be controller should return cookies, but i don't know which ones.

Comment: i ment it like it authentificates by this uri, and then connects to hub. but w/e.
right now it's enough for me to know what cookies should return controller of asp.net.Identity as login api?

Comment: Yeah, the example is illustrating that you need to populate `connection.CookieContainer` with the authentication detail.  To do that you need access to the response headers, which you don't have at the `hub.Invoke()` level, so you need to make a non-signalr request to set it up.

Comment: Well, it is open source so if you wanted to maybe you could add it yourself :)